# Handler postDelay() from background thread

Tags: java, kotlin, runnable, android-handler, android-looper

Can anyone see any reason why this would not be working?

```
 override fun resetAnimations() {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "start")
    Handler().postDelayed( { reset()}, 1500)
    Log.d("MainActivity", "end")
 }

 fun reset(){
     Log.d("MainActivity", "reset")
  }
```

I'm calling this in some arbitrary place in my activity but the reset() method is never called. In the logs I'm only getting the following

```
D/MainActivity: start
```

It looks like its blocking on postDelay.. even when I set the value to 1 or replace postDelay with pose, doesn't work.

Update:

when i implement like this, it works;

```
 private lateinit var handler : Handler

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    handler = Handler()
    resetAnimations()
 }

 override fun resetAnimations() {
    handler.postDelayed( { reset()}, 1500)
 }
```

I think the problem has something to do with the fact that I was calling resetAnimations() from a background thread, and creating the handler on the background thread..

Comment: probaly you are never calling resetAnimations

Comment: @crgarridos updated y question there. Obviously I'm calling resetAnimations!

Comment: Then you are calling resetAnimation from another thread than mainThread ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was calling `resetAnimations()` from a background thread.

That's the problem. Your handler couldn't post a `Message` onto a `MessageQueue`, because there isn't any `MessageQueue` on your background thread.

So, instead of this:

```
Handler().postDelayed( { reset()}, 1500)
```

Perform this:

```
Handler(Looper.getMainThread()).postDelayed( { reset()}, 1500)
```

Comment: yeah that was it. Thnaks! Would that throw some sort of exception in java that gets swallowed in kotlin?

Comment: @sirFunkenstine, none that I know about.